# having trouble with an EditText control box

Tags: java, android, xml, textbox, edit

in my application I have 3 edit boxes where the user enters in text.
After the text is entered into the three boxes, I want to press the save button and have the data saved.  I am trying to figure out how to do that and all the reading that I am doing I am not finding it.  Can someone give me some guidance??

Here is my code so far from the java file:

```
package com.example.gasfillup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GasFillup extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Car Info").setContent(R.id.panel1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Fillup Info").setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Gas Milage").setContent(R.id.textview3));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Stats").setContent(R.id.textview4));       
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.panel1);
        String txt = tv.getText().toString();


    }
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong ... I want to be able to understand what I don't know ...

ironmantis7x

Comment: Do you have a database set up?

Comment: No I do not --- how do I do that in my app??  I assume it would be a small version of sql?  I want to be able to save the data so that the user can pull the data later and then have it shown on a plot later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have a `Button` declared.  You will also need to set an `onClickListener` on the `Button` that actually performs the data save.  You also haven't said where you want the data to be saved to, `SharedPreferences`, a `File`, database etc.

Comment: OH --- okay!!  That makes sense!!  This goes in the .java file (correct)??  Forgive me -- I am very new to Java and android!

Comment: @ironmantis7x I would suggest you work your way through the [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)

Comment: I didn't see a tutorial for a database on the android site (or maybe I missed it)??

Comment: @dave.c I didn't see a tutorial on databases on the android site (or maybe I missed it)??